# Junit Ant Integration Problems

Tags: ant, junit

I've a separate junit test case and it is integrated with the ant script. The separate junit works fine and the test case passes. When it is executed with the ant integration it fails.

The test case and the ant script are as below,

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest 
{

    @Test
    public void testHello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }


}
```

the ant script is,

```
<property file="build.properties" />

<path id="libirary">

    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="**.*jar" />
    </fileset>

</path>




<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>


<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac encoding="ISO-8859-1" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" srcdir="${src.dir}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="libirary" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">

    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${jar.filename}.jar">

        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" />
        <zipfileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.file.name}" />
        </manifest>

    </jar>
</target>


<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit   printsummary="yes" description="true" filtertrace="yes" >

        <classpath path="${lib}">
            <path refid="libirary" />
        </classpath>
        <test name="SimpleTest">
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>
```

The output is,

```
Buildfile: D:\Workspaces\TrunkForCheckIn-31-05-2013\PG\build.xml
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory 
   [delete] Deleting directory 
   [delete] Deleting directory 
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: 
    [mkdir] Created dir: 
compile:
    [javac]  warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 57 source files to 
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
junit:
    [junit] Running SimpleTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.bosch.in.stepage.pg.SimpleTest FAILED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a plain formatter:

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
    <junit   printsummary="yes" description="true" filtertrace="yes" >
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
        <classpath path="${lib}">
            <path refid="libirary" />
        </classpath>
        <test name="SimpleTest">
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response
Hi From the verbose I was able to find that the class not found exception was the cause and even after giving the following code, it is not picking up the class, 
<classpath>
    <pathelement path="${build.classes.dir}" />
   </classpath>